# Visual Studio HELPVIEWER doesn't open when I press <F1> in C# project; but it works ok in VB project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Am using VISUAL STUDIO 2017 PRO.
I've converted a 20000 line VB project to C, by using VBConversions (works great 99.9%), which auto-creates the resulting C# project.

But, in resultant C# project,  doesn't popup Help Viewer, even though  works great as always in VB project.
Help is set for "launch in help viewer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, closing and re-opening C# project solved it.  HV now opens upon .